# Creating a system of linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

An average mark is computed for 100 students in Business, an average is 
computed for 300 students in Arts, and an average is computed for 200 students 
in Science. The average of these three averages is 85%. However, the overall 
average for the 600 students is 86%. Also, the average for the 300 students in
Business and Science is 4 marks higher than the average for the students in 
Arts. Determine the average for each group of students by solving a 
system of linear equations.

Let $x,y,z$ represent the students in business, arts and science respectively.

$\frac{1}{6}x+\frac{3}{6}y+\frac{2}{6}z=0.85$

$\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{3}y+\frac{1}{3}z=0.86$

$\frac{1}{6}x-y+\frac{1}{3}z=0.04$

But when I solve for these 3 equations I end up getting $x=0.48666$,$y=0.54666$, and $z=1.51666$, which I dont believe is correct.

I believe that some of my equations are wrong, could someone tell me which one?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equation should be the average of the three averages, so it should not be weighted: the correct form is $\frac{1}{3}x + \frac{1}{3}y + \frac{1}{3}z = 0.85$.

The second is the overall average, so it is weighted. Basically, it is your first equation set equal to $0.86$.

I believe the third equation is correct. I would like to remark though, that x, y and z represent the averages, not the students.

Comment: When I use your first equation with my other 2, it follows that the system becomes inconsistent. Anything im doing wrong?

Comment: @user183678 You want to swap the first and second answers to get the correct system, so you are changing two equations.

Comment: ah sorry! now that I use the 2 modified equations I still end up with the answers i got before with $x=0.48666$,$y=0.54666$, and $z=1.51666$

Comment: @user183678 If you modified the equations, you should definitely not be getting the same answers. That is impossible. Your first equation should be equal to 0.86 and your second equation should be equal to 0.85. Looking at the question again, I think that the third equation should be $\frac{1}{3}x - y + \frac{2}{3}z = 0.04$ (Why?).

Comment: Yeah how does the third equation become that?
Also, after plugging in all 3 modified formulas, I end up with $x=0.78$. $y=0.84$,$z=0.93$, which looks must better now!

Comment: @user183678 You are calculating the average over the 300 students in science and business. Therefore, you need to compute the average for those students only, which is given by $\frac{1}{3}x + \frac{2}{3}y$ and subtract $y$ from that.

Comment: got it thanks a lot!